# setMaxBounds does not set max bounds

Tags: r, leaflet, r-leaflet

`setMaxBounds` does not restrict the rectangle displayed to the coordinates specified.

On zooming in multiple times (5 on my browser), it gets 'close to' the specified rectangle, as shown in the table.

Minimal example

```
library(shiny)
library(leaflet)
ui <- fluidPage(
  column(6,
         leafletOutput('maxmap')
  )
  ,
  column(6,
         tableOutput('bbox')
  )
)
server <- function(input, output) {
  output$bbox <- renderTable(
    data.frame(Lat=c(input$maxmap_bounds$north,input$maxmap_bounds$south),
               Long=c(input$maxmap_bounds$east,input$maxmap_bounds$west)
    )
  )
  output$maxmap <- renderLeaflet({
    leaflet(width=500,height=400) %>%
      addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>%
      setMaxBounds(lng1 = 10, lat1 = 20, lng2=11, lat2=21)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This may be related to a closed issue on github [setMaxBounds() sets minZoom level wrong](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/2011)

I am using R3.4.1 leaflet 1.1.0 on Windows

Have I misunderstood what setMaxBounds is supposed to do?  I am experimenting with it because setView seems also to produce unexpected results, sometimes needing zooming to achieve the desired 'window', sometimes spot on.

[edit] at the suggestion of MLavoie I made the following modification and it works fine to within 1%, as shown in the tabulation in shiny.  I'll mark as the answer.

```
output$maxmap <- renderLeaflet({
leaflet(width=500,height=400) %>%
  addProviderTiles('CartoDB.Positron') %>%
  setMaxBounds(lng1 = 10, lat1 = 20, lng2=11, lat2=21) %>%
  setView(zoom=RgoogleMaps::MaxZoom(latrange=20:21, lonrange=10:11, size = c(500, 400)),lat=20.5, lng=10.5)
  })
```

Comment: you also need to use `maxZoom` to get what you want.

Comment: hmm seems I can't accept a comment as a solution, so I guess I'll just upvote @MLavoie and leave it thus.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1555/mark-a-comment-as-answer-to-a-question